# Is there a way to call snackbar.make() without a view in Android?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to call Snackbar.make() on a second Android activity in a Flutter project, the activity does not have a view, since its function is to capture an intent and show the snackbar. Is there any way to achieve this?

I've tried

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "This is Simple Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

but I get the following error:

```
W/ActivityThread( 3220): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@83aa67d
D/AndroidRuntime( 3220): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220): Process: com.example.app, PID: 3220
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220): java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7348)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 696(935KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(1272KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 36MB/42MB, paused 825us total 618.409ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 159254(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 39MB/45MB, paused 745us total 126.988ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 194697(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 39MB/45MB, paused 738us total 127.174ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 197332(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 40MB/46MB, paused 1.290ms total 129.845ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 202012(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 40MB/46MB, paused 826us total 124.915ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 206764(21MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 40MB/46MB, paused 1.205ms total 127.143ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 199355(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 39MB/45MB, paused 801us total 123.477ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 194717(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 39MB/45MB, paused 771us total 122.645ms
I/chatty  ( 3220): uid=10092(com.example.app) identical 3067 lines
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7354)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.View.resetRtlProperties(View.java:17877)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5085)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4865)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4837)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:451)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:432)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2791)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at com.example.link.UrlActivity.onCreate(UrlActivity.java:32)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3220):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 194396(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 43MB/49MB, paused 827us total 188.221ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 181046(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 9(3MB) LOS objects, 8% free, 62MB/68MB, paused 766us total 159.861ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 336212(32MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(10MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 69MB/75MB, paused 830us total 260.882ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 386099(37MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 92MB/98MB, paused 1.083ms total 206.463ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 343198(33MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(13MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 78MB/84MB, paused 800us total 158.032ms
I/.example.app( 3220): Background concurrent copying GC freed 334743(32MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 96MB/102MB, paused 863us total 142.773ms
I/Process ( 3220): Sending signal. PID: 3220 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Here is the Activity

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class UrlActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();


        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)){
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            String urlString = "";

            try{
                URL url = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
                    // Toast.makeText(UrlActivity.this, finalUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Toast works fine, used for testing
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), url.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();                                
            }catch (MalformedURLException ex){
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), ex.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            }


        }
        else{
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), "Error getting info", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        finish();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get a snackbar in this scenario?

Comment: No. Use a Toast instead.

Comment: I need to use an action on the snackbar, otherwise I would use a Toast

Answer (score 0):

You could try and call it with `findViewById(android.R.content.id)`. Otherwise, you may need to call `setContentView(...)` with some arbitray `View` that fills the screen.